# Getting Http Error Code 411 : Length Required

Tags: c#, .net, rest, httpclient

When I am trying to upload a file using following code I am receiving Length Required error. Please note that if I am uploading a TEXT file then I don't see any issues. But when I upload WORD or PDF I am seeing the error. FYI, I am able to see to Content-Length in my request header in both occasions. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
internal static class CreateFile
{
    private static string _Server = "MyServer.com";
    private static string _Database = "ACTIVE";

    internal static async Task<string> CreateFileInFolder(string _AuthToken, string _FolderId, string _FileLocation)
    {
        // Force TLS 1.2 instead of the default value.
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        //folder creation URI
        string _FileCreateUri = $"https://{_Server}/api/v2/customers/1/libraries/{_Database}/folders/{_FolderId}/documents";

        FileInfo _FileDetails = new (_FileLocation);

        string _Result = "";

        FileRoot _FileRoot = new()
        {
            doc_profile = new FileProfile()
            {
                author = "ADMIN",
                comment = "New Import",
                default_security = "private",
                name = _FileDetails.Name,
                custom1 = "Test",
                custom2 = "Test",
                custom17 = "12345",
                access = "full_access",
                database = _Database,
                size = _FileDetails.Length,
                @class = "DOC",
                type = "ACROBAT",
                type_description = "",
                wstype = "document"
            },
            audit = new FileAudit()
            {
                comments = "Test Import"
            },
            keep_locked = false,
            warnings_for_required_and_disabled_fields = true
        };

        byte[] _FileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(_FileDetails.FullName);
        string _Boundary = $"----------{DateTime.Now.Ticks:x}";

        MultipartFormDataContent _MultipartFormDataContent  = new(_Boundary)
        {
            {
                JsonContent.Create(_FileRoot), "profile" 
            },
            { 
                new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(_FileBytes), _FileBytes.Length), "file"
            }
        };

        _MultipartFormDataContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
        _MultipartFormDataContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", $"multipart/form-data; boundary={_Boundary}");

        using (HttpClient _HttpClient = new())
        {
            //include authentication token in request header
            _HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", _AuthToken);

            using (HttpResponseMessage _HttpResMsg = await _HttpClient.PostAsync(_FileCreateUri, _MultipartFormDataContent))
            {
                if (_HttpResMsg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    _Result = _HttpResMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }      

        //MessageBox.Show($"Json profile newly created folder: {_HttpResMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result}", "New Folder Profile", MessageBoxButton.OK);

        return _Result;
    }

    public class FileAudit
    {
        public string comments { get; set; }
    }

    public class FileProfile
    {
        public string author { get; set; }
        public string access { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public string @class { get; set; }
        public string database { get; set; }
        public string default_security { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public long size { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string type_description { get; set; }
        public string wstype { get; set; }
        public string custom1 { get; set; }
        public string custom2 { get; set; }
        public string custom17 { get; set; }
    }

    public class FileRoot
    {
        public FileProfile doc_profile { get; set; }
        public FileAudit audit { get; set; }
        public bool keep_locked { get; set; }
        public bool warnings_for_required_and_disabled_fields { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Tried to use HttpRequestMessage by setting Content-Length but again able to upload TEXT files but not WORD or PDF files.

Comment: My suggestion would be to convert the binary data to a base64 string and pass it that way.

Comment: I think this is something to do with web config, does the server support GET, because http server works different if you upload large files using multipart

Comment: I think it has something to do with the file size. Even for Text files if they are more than 12 KB I am getting Length Required Error. So not sure why it is doing so. By default server allows up to 4 GB.

Please note that I am writing a windows based application.

Comment: After further investigation it I am receiving Content Length required error whenever the file is Chunked. That is "Transfer-Encoding: chunked". Any idea how can I avoid this?

Comment: Issue resolved, in my case its the problem with payload due lack of proper documentation from product vendor.